# Laravel 9 JWT logout problem php-open-source-saver/jwt-auth

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, laravel-9

I tried use php-open-source-saver/jwt-auth by tutorial https://blog.logrocket.com/implementing-jwt-authentication-laravel-9/

Its working fine but I have some problem with logout.

```
Auth::logout();
```

When I logout and then try call my test method its working with old token.

```
class SubjectController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api');
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $subject = Subject::find($id);

        return response(json_encode($subject))
            ->header('Content-Type','application/json');
    }
}
```

Comment: Same problem here, did you solve? The suggested solution doesn't work for me. Neither with ```invalidate()``` method

Comment: It was able to use before but suddenly not working, did you guys found out any solution?

Answer (score 0):

check document : https://laravel-jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auth-guard/

```
logout()
```

Log the user out - which will invalidate the current token and unset the authenticated user.

```
auth()->logout();

// Pass true to force the token to be blacklisted "forever"
auth()->logout(true);
```